# How to rename multiple uniquely name directories on a mapped drive with unique names in a batch file

Tags: batch, mapped-drive

I have a mapped drive with multiple uniquely named folders containing files.  I want to rename each folder with a batch file.

```
V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>dir
 Volume in drive V is DATA3
 Volume Serial Number is 50CF-6A6E

 Directory of V:\Media\Elton John\Singles

2021-04-17  05:16 AM    <DIR>          .
2020-09-22  10:14 AM    <DIR>          ..
2021-04-09  06:47 AM    <DIR>          1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)
2021-04-09  07:36 AM    <DIR>          1970-07 Border Song - Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)
2021-04-09  06:50 AM    <DIR>          1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)
.
.
.
```

I want to rename each uniquely named directory with a unique name  - examples:

```
1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)"
1970-07 Border Song - Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)
1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)
```

I created a batch file - the pauses are so I can abort the batch file if there are problems:

```
ren "1969 - Lady Samantha. All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF1739)" "1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)"
PAUSE
ren "1971 - Border Song. Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)" "1970-07 Border Song - Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)"
PAUSE
ren "1970 - Rock'n'Roll Madonna. Grey Seal (7'', Supreme DJS 222)" "1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)"
```

I ran it and got:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\

C:\WINDOWS\system32>V:

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\EJSingles.bat

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren "1969 - Lady Samantha. All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF1739)" "1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)"
The system cannot find the file specified.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren "1971 - Border Song. Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)" "1970-07 Border Song - Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)"
The system cannot find the file specified.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren "1970 - Rock'n'Roll Madonna. Grey Seal (7'', Supreme DJS 222)" "1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)"
The system cannot find the file specified.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>
```

I stripped out the quotes and got:

```
V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\EJSingles.bat

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren 1969 - Lady Samantha. All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF1739) 1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren 1971 - Border Song. Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246) 1970-07 Border Song - Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren 1970 - Rock'n'Roll Madonna. Grey Seal (7'', Supreme DJS 222) 1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>
```

I added the complete path to the batch file:

```
ren "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1969 - Lady Samantha. All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF1739)" "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)"
PAUSE
ren "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970 - Take Me To The Pilot. Your Song (7'', UNI 55265)" "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970-10 Take Me To The Pilot - Your Song (7'', UNI 55265)"
PAUSE
ren "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970 - Rock'n'Roll Madonna. Grey Seal (7'', Supreme DJS 222)" "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)"
```

I got:

```
V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\EJSingles.bat

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1969 - Lady Samantha. All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF1739)" "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)"
The system cannot find the file specified.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970 - Take Me To The Pilot. Your Song (7'', UNI 55265)" "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970-10 Take Me To The Pilot - Your Song (7'', UNI 55265)"
The system cannot find the file specified.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970 - Rock'n'Roll Madonna. Grey Seal (7'', Supreme DJS 222)" "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)"
The system cannot find the file specified.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>
```

Lastly I tried using the complete path without quotes:

```
V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\EJSingles.bat

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1969 - Lady Samantha. All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF1739) V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970 - Take Me To The Pilot. Your Song (7'', UNI 55265) V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970-10 Take Me To The Pilot - Your Song (7'', UNI 55265)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>ren V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970 - Rock'n'Roll Madonna. Grey Seal (7'', Supreme DJS 222) V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

V:\Media\Elton John\Singles>
```

I'm using Notepad to write the batch file - Word Wrap IS NOT on.

I'm probably forgetting something simple.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Go to your `/D`rive:

```
cd /D "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\."
```

**2** Use (keep using) `"`Double Quotes`"` in path with special character and/or spaces...

**3.** The target name not use/need the full path\folder strings, only new names...

```
@echo off

cd /D "V:\Media\Elton John\Singles\."

ren .\"1969 - Lady Samantha. All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF1739)" "1969-01 Lady Samantha - All Across The Heavens (7'', Philips BF 1739)"
ren .\"1971 - Border Song. Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)" "1970-07 Border Song - Bad Side Of The Moon (7'', UNI 55246)"
ren .\"1970 - Rock'n'Roll Madonna. Grey Seal (7'', Supreme DJS 222)" "1970-08 Rock And Roll Madonna - Grey Seal (7'', Supreme S. 147)"

%__AppDir__%Timeout.exe /t -1 | dir /a:d /b "1969*" "1971*" "1970*"
```